# How to pass the "isActive" state given by NavLink (in react-router v6.8.1) to its children's className?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I am unable to pass the `isActive` state from the `Navlink` to its children's `className` (`item.icon` and `span`).

```
<ul className="flex flex-col gap-2 px-3">
  {sidebarLinks.map((item) => {
    return (
      <li key={item.name}>
        <NavLink
          to={item.href}
          className={({ isActive }) => isActive
            ? "group flex cursor-pointer items-center gap-3 rounded-md bg-gray-200 px-3 py-2 transition-all"
            : "group flex cursor-pointer items-center gap-3 rounded-md px-3 py-2 transition-all hover:bg-gray-200 "
          }
        >
          {/* <item.icon
            className={`h-5 stroke-gray-400 stroke-2 group-hover:stroke-blue-700`}
          /> */}
          {/* -------------------PROBLEM STARTS IS FROM HERE----------------------*/}
          <item.icon
            className={`h-5 stroke-2 ${({ isActive }) => isActive
              ? "stroke-blue-700"
              : "stroke-gray-400"}`
            }
          />
          <span
            className={`font-semibold text-gray-700 group-hover:text-gray-900 ${
              ({ isActive, }) => (isActive ? "text-red-800" : "text-green-700")
            }`}
          >
            {item.name}
          </span>
        </NavLink>
      </li>
    );
  })}
</ul>
```

This is what is shows on inspecting:

[image: On Inspecting the Children's classname]

I tried to store the `isActive` state to a new state variable, but react denies it and throws error.

I have also tried to store the boolean value of it in some variable. But I am unable to do so either.

What I am expecting is to carry forward the `isActive` state from the parent `NavLink` to its children elements (an `icon` and a `span`).

Please correct me if I am doing something wrong.

Answer (score 0):

you can't use isActive in span and item.icon className props like NaveLisk's className prop,
but you can use this method :

```
<ul className="flex flex-col gap-2 px-3">
  {sidebarLinks.map((item) => {
    return (
      <li key={item.name}>
        <NavLink
          to={item.href}
          className={({ isActive }) =>
            isActive
              ? "group flex cursor-pointer items-center gap-3 rounded-md bg-gray-200 px-3 py-2 transition-all"
              : "group flex cursor-pointer items-center gap-3 rounded-md px-3 py-2 transition-all hover:bg-gray-200 "
          }
        >{({isActive})=>{
            return (<>
            <item.icon 
              className={ isActive ? "h-5 stroke-2 stroke-blue-700" : "stroke-gray-400"}
            />
              <span
                className={`font-semibold text-gray-700 group-hover:text-gray-900 ${isActive ? "text-red-800" : "text-green-700"}`}
              >{item.name}</span>
            </>)
          }}
        </NavLink>
      </li>
    );
  })}
</ul>
```

i send this function as NavLink Children :

```
{({isActive})=>{
            return (<>
            <item.icon 
              className={ isActive ? "h-5 stroke-2 stroke-blue-700" : "stroke-gray-400"}
            />
              <span
                className={`font-semibold text-gray-700 group-hover:text-gray-900 ${isActive ? "text-red-800" : "text-green-700"}`}
              >{item.name}</span>
            </>)
          }}
```

Comment: But `NavLink` with return an anchor tag `a` and `<></>` returns a `div`. We can not really use `<div>` inside `<a>`, is not it?. But thank you for your approach. Though it didn't exactly work for my case. But I have used your approach to figure it out.

Comment: <></> not return div. test on app.

Comment: <></> and <React.Fragment /> return empty not any tag